# Active record join query issue in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, left-join

I am using join query in `Rails application` where i got success record but i need to `fetch record` where updated date greater than yesterday date or created date greater than yesterday.

How to query `OR between updated_date and created_date?`

So i fired below query but issues there.

```
@courses = Course.includes(:translations).where(course_translations: {status: 'active'}, published: true, created_at: time_range, updated_at: time_range)
```

Still not get any solutions. Any one have a idea then please share with me.

Comment: published,created_at,updated_at is a field of course_translations?

Comment: No, its a fields of courses. I want to put or condition between updated_at and created_at.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try this way

```
start_date =  Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day
end_date = Time.zone.now.end_of_day
@courses = Course.includes(:translations).where(course_translations: {status: 'active'}, published: true).where("courses.created_at Between ? And ? or courses .updated_at Between ? And ?", start_date,end_date,start_date,end_date).
```

Comment: It will throw an error, because of ambiguity for created_at and updated_at

Comment: @GouravNaik you need to put your table name for resolving these issue updated post

Comment: Ya i was knowing, but while answering we have to take care of it, as OP may not know about it

Answer (score -1):

Hope it gives your desired output

```
Course.includes(:translations).where("course_translations.status =? and courses.published =? and (courses.created_at > ? or courses.updated_at > ?)",'active',true,Date.yesterday.end_of_day,Date.yesterday.end_of_day)
```

Let me know your results

Comment: Op wants `created_at` and `updated_at` grater than yesterday date not from yesterday

Comment: instead of using `Date.yesterday` use `Date.yesterday.end_of_day` otherwise it return all records created on `Date.yesterday` because of time difference. so query returns wrong records

Comment: My answers works perfectly according to OP requirement. There is no valid reason for devoting it

Comment: i guess if you fetch record according to you query it returns if Date.yesterday is `Thu, 25 Feb 2016` then it return record with created_at `Thu, 25 Feb 2016 15:36:10` according to OP needs greater than yesterday i.e from Today. read previous comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104643/discussion-between-gourav-naik-and-vishal-jain).

Comment: I have given greater than Date.yesterday not >= so it wont fetch record of yesterday. anyways let OP be happy.

Comment: are u sure it will not return yesterday record by replacing `>=` to `>`?? because `Date.yesterday` return or consider as start of day so `Thu, 25 Feb 2016 15:36:10` this value is also greater than `Date.yesterday` by time difference. have u check this??